# How to log the entire git history of a file that is renamed/moved using its old path?

Tags: git, version-control

If a file, `A`, is edited one or more times, then renamed/moved to `B` and edited one or more times as `B`, issuing the following git command using its new name/path ...

```
git log --follow -- B
```

... shows its entire history.

However, when I'm looking at an old (released/maintained) branch of the same project where the file is still named `A` and I want to backport changes done to it in `master`, I might think that issuing the following on `master` ...

```
git log --follow -- A
```

... will show me *all* changes. But it does not. The latest commit displayed in the log is the change corresponding to the rename from `A` to `B`. Changes done to `B` are not shown.

i.e. `--follow` only follows renames "backwards" from a newer name to an older one, but not "forwards".

At this point, I have to first identify that the latest commit displayed is a rename, find the newer name, and issue a `git log --follow` again with the new name (and potentially repeat this several times if the file was moved around a few times since the maintained release.

How can I find the entire history without having to manually issue `git log --follow` several times?

Comment: You _can't_ always trace every move/rename operation, because sometimes Git can't figure it out.  Not an answer, but the best bet is to avoid moving/renaming files in Git, if you can manage that.

Comment: I don't think there's a great solution for this because Git doesn't really move forwards in history like you describe, but I can recommend the flag `--name-status` for `git log` (and others) which shows you what kinds of changes were made to each file in each commit (e.g. `M` = modified, `R` = renamed).

Comment: @JanKrüger, nice! A `git log --oneline --name-status` without a pathspec is a pretty good candidate for grepping through and looking for renames.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, `git log` itself strictly works *backwards*, as Git always does.  Git literally cannot work forwards because what Git has stored *is* backwards: each commit remembers the hash ID of its parent commit, but since all commits are frozen in time the moment they are created, they cannot remember the hash IDs of their children, who are created later.

What `git log` (and its sort of big sister / workhorse plumbing command `git rev-list`) *can* do is do this reverse traversal once, figuring out which commits go before which other commits, then *print* in reverse.  The `git log --reverse` command does this.  But alas, rename detection happens only during the backwards (which to Git is forwards) traversal and cannot be wedged into the later forwards (which to Git is backwards) printout.

It's not built in to Git, but you can use `git rev-list` to do the reversal, save the result, then do *your own* forwards walk while running `git diff --name-status` on each commit pair, looking for rename operations.  Note that this is still a bit tricky since now branches really branch and merges really merge—in Git's internal backwards traversals, merges branch, while branches merge. :-)  That is, suppose we have:

```
  tag:abc
     |
     v
...--o--o--*--o--o--o   <-- tip1
         \
          o--*--o----o   <-- tip2
```

You want to start from tag `abc`, which is on the left, and "work forwards".  Git wants to start from either `tip1`, the commit towards the right along the top line, or `tip2`, the commit towards the right on the bottom line.

The commits marked `*` rename your file `A` to some new name.  In the one along the top the new name is `B` and in the one along the bottom the new name is `C`.

If you start Git at `tip2`, you must look for `C`.  Git notices the rename in `*` and from then on, towards the left, looks for `A`.  If you start Git at `tip1`, you must look for `B`, in the same fashion.

If you've built a "forwards" listing by going backwards from `tip1` to some point before tag `abc`, you'll be OK: there's no branch in that listing since none of the commits leading to `tip2` are included.  But then suppose someone adds a *merge* to `tip1`, and another commit:

```
  tag:abc
     |
     v
...--o--o--*--o--o--o--M--o   <-- tip1
         \            /
          o--*--o----o   <-- tip2
```

Now the path from `abc` to `tip1` includes *both* renames.  If you start at `tip1` you must give `git log --follow` the name that whoever did the merge chose to keep, whether that's `B` or `C`.  Because `git log -- B` or `git log -- C` (whichever is the right name) does *history simplification*, Git is going to walk only *one* of the two legs behind `M`–either the top or bottom row, depending on which one has the matching file—and when you work forwards from `abc` you'll have to pick one of the two *branches* to work along, or do something fancy so that you know to check for `A`-becomes-`B` along the *top* while also checking for `A`-becomes-`C` along the *bottom*.  (Git doesn't do anything fancy.)